# Why does my populated 3 week schedule return false for today?

Tags: sql-server

I built an application desinged to be a online menu for a cafeteria. But for some reason even with it being populated it is not returning any items for today. Here is the SQL query that I am using to pull the items out:

```
Select num, FoodItem, Week, Day, Station, Site 
  from FoodMenu WHERE [Week] = (DATEPART(WEEK, GETDATE()) % 3) + 1 
  AND [Day] = DATEPART(DW, GETDATE()) -1
```

Monday is set up as `Day 1` and Sunday is set up as `Day 7`

Comment: That -1 looks suspicious

Comment: @lc. is there another way I should be doing it. Without the negative 1 in place sunday would read as saturday and it would throuw the cycle off. I agree that the query needs to be fixed but how?!?

Comment: Please read: https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The -1 looks incorrect because it would yield the following results (note the 0 for Sunday when you actually want 7):

```
 Day      | DOW | Transformed
Sunday    |   1 | 0
Monday    |   2 | 1
Tuesday   |   3 | 2
Wednesday |   4 | 3
Thursday  |   5 | 4
Friday    |   6 | 5
Saturday  |   7 | 6
```

What you really want is:

```
 Day      | DOW | Transformed
Sunday    |   1 | 7
Monday    |   2 | 1
Tuesday   |   3 | 2
Wednesday |   4 | 3
Thursday  |   5 | 4
Friday    |   6 | 5
Saturday  |   7 | 6
```

The simplest way to do this is with a case:

```
[Day] = CASE WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) = 1 THEN 7 ELSE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) - 1 END
```

Comment: mod 7 returns the range 0-6

Comment: @lc. So do I need to change sunday to be `Day 7` ?

Comment: @Skullomania Your question states the data has Sunday as day "7" so my answer would be yes

Comment: Nevermind...i see what you did there....its late and im getting slower by the moment...thanks bro!